Only Top Row of Confusion Matrix Shows Numbers
I am trying to show a confusion matrix from a 2d tensor, "cm". When I print the tensor it shows all the correct values that need to be displayed on the confusion matrix, however, when I put the tensor into the seaborn heatmap only the top row of values is shown
cm = tf.math.confusion_matrix(ground_truths, predictions, num_classes=4)

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, fmt='g', cmap='Blues', 
            xticklabels=list(idx_to_cls.values()), 
            yticklabels=list(idx_to_cls.values()))
plt.xlabel('Predicted')
plt.ylabel('True')
plt.title('Confusion Matrix')
plt.show()

only top row of numbers from the cm object shows in the confusion matrix
I tried converting the tensor into a numpy array but it didn't work. I suspect it's because the cm object is already a 2d tensor. I did find one solution from the below link but thought I'd see if anyone had any other solutions other than downgrading their matplotlib version.
https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/3478

You can upgrade your seaborn version. The problem is solved in seaborn 0.13.
